# Modifications to Swagger UI header

Tags: asp.net-web-api, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I have created a personal WEB API using Swashbuckle and Swagger API.

While I am able to integrate this successfully, I would like to modify the default UI for Swagger. Changing the color of the header and replacing the swagger image.

[image: Attached is the part of the imagine I want to change.]

Is this possible by modifying existing files?

Comment: The color can be changed by injecting css through the swaggerconfig.cs file.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

These are the steps I took:

1. Create a new file SwaggerHeader.css
2. Right click on `SwaggerHeader.css`, select **Properties**. Set **Build** action to **Embedded Resource**.
3. In `SwaggerConfig.cs`, add the below line of code:

```cs
      EnableSwaggerUi("Document/{*assetPath}", c =>
      {
          c.InjectStylesheet(typeof(SwaggerConfig).Assembly,
          "ProjectName.FolderName.SwaggerHeader.css");
      }
```

4. `SwaggerHeader.css` looks like the below:

```html
/* swagger ui customization */
body.swagger-section #header {
    background-color: white;
    background: url(your-new-logo.png) no-repeat;
    background-position-x: 250px;
    height: 50px;
}

body.swagger-section #header .swagger-ui-wrap #logo {
        display: none;
}
```

Comment: In `ProjectName.FolderName.SwaggerHeader.css`, what's `ProjectName.FolderName` ? Is it the assembly namespace?

Comment: In #3, you're missing a double-quote before "ProjectName"

Comment: #5, add image to dir

Answer (score 7):

[image]

Startup

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
           

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            
            .....................
            .....................

            app.UseSwagger();

            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
              
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json",  "API V1");
            
                c.InjectStylesheet("/css/swagger-custom.css");
            });

            
        }
```

Swagger custom css

```
img[alt="Swagger UI"] {
    display: block;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    content: url('../images/logo.png');
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
.swagger-section #header {
    background-color: #fff !important;
   
}

.swagger-ui .topbar {
    padding: 10px 0;
    background-color: #fff !important;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dee2e6 !important;
}
    .swagger-ui .topbar .download-url-wrapper .select-label {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 600px;
        margin: 0;
        color: #121416 !important;
        
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

1. First step is to add a new css file in your project, with your custom rules.
   For example :

   ```
   .swagger-section #header { background-color: #fadc00; }
   ```
2. Right click on the new file and go Properties. In "Build Actions" select "Embedded Ressources".
3. Inside the SwaggerConfig file, inject the stylesheet. The resource name should be the **"Logical Name"** for the resource. That is where I got stuck, but thanks to [this Swashbuckle doc](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/wiki/3-Customizing-the-swagger-ui#injecting-custom-content) I could infer the logical name following the rule :

   *Default Namespace for your project "dot" folder containing the resource "dot" file name with extension.*

> It's based on the Project's default namespace, file location and file
>   extension. For example, given a default namespace of
>   "YourWebApiProject" and a file located at
>   "/SwaggerExtensions/index.html", then the resource will be assigned
>   the name - "YourWebApiProject.SwaggerExtensions.index.html"

For example :

```
.EnableSwaggerUi(c =>
{
    c.InjectStylesheet(thisAssembly, "Some.Default.Namespace.App_Start.swagger.css");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

To change the color, you can inject a new stylesheet

Qoute from the SwaggerConfig.cs file

> Use the "InjectStylesheet" option to enrich the UI with one or more a dditional CSS stylesheets.
>    The file must be included in your project as an "Embedded Resource", and then the resource's
>    "Logical Name" is passed to the method as shown below.
>    `c.InjectStylesheet(containingAssembly,"Swashbuckle.Dummy.SwaggerExtensions.testStyles1.css");`

Remember to set Build Action of the stylesheet to "Embedded Resource".

Answer (score 1):

Alternativelly, I have created a *custom.css* in my *wwwroot* folder and just added

```
options.InjectStylesheet("/custom.css");
```

and it worked as well.