# How to Integrate Custom css in Swagger WebApi

Tags: asp.net-web-api, swagger

Actually, My project name is “**Ecommerce.Service**”. How can I add custom css into this.

How do I add this into

```
c.InjectStylesheet(containingAssembly, " Ecommerce.Service.Contect.MyStyle.css");
```

which is not able to get the css path. Please help.

Comment: Does this help? [Modifications to Swagger UI header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36291146/modifications-to-swagger-ui-header)